# Seleccionar archivo por minuto más bajo - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, filtro

tengo el siguiente código en Python 2.7:

```
for file in files:  #vamos leyendo cada archivo uno a uno
    fecha=file[12:20]
    soloFecha=fecha
    anio=fecha[4:8]
    mes=fecha[2:4]
    dia=fecha[0:2]
    hora=file[-8:-6]
    minuto=file[-6:-4]

    if fechaSelect==soloFecha: #Para que solo coja los archivos del mismo dia que hemos seleccionado
        if int(hora) == 0:
            self.lineEdit2_0.setText(file)
            self.lineEdit1_0e_2.setText(os.path.join(ruta, file))
            self.label2_0.setText(dia +'/'+ mes +'/'+ anio +'  '+ hora +':'+ minuto)
        elif int(hora) == 1:
            self.lineEdit2_1.setText(file)
            self.lineEdit1_1e_2.setText(os.path.join(ruta, file))
            self.label2_1.setText(dia +'/'+ mes +'/'+ anio +'  '+ hora +':'+ minuto)
```

y continuaría para las 24 horas del día.

El asunto es que para cada hora hay varios archivos y sólo quiero quedarme con el que tenga el minuto más pequeño. Es decir si hay un archivo con hora 00:10 y otro con hora 00:15 y otro con 00:30, quiero que tan solo use el de las 00:10.
La hora la cojo del nombre de cada archivo.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Gracias

Comment: Iría bien que pusieras la salida de `print files`, para ver más claro el formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# definimos una variable para guardar resultados    
result = {} 

    for file in files:
        fecha=file[12:20]
        soloFecha=fecha
        anio=fecha[4:8]
        mes=fecha[2:4]
        dia=fecha[0:2]
        hora=file[-8:-6]
        # convertimos minuto en entero
        minuto=int(file[-6:-4])

        if fechaSelect==soloFecha:
            # si la hora está en result y el minuto es mayor al actual
            # o la hora no está aún
            if hora in result and result[hora]["min"] > minuto \
                    or hora not in result:
                result[hora] = {"file": file, "min": minuto}
```

result será un diccionario con la hora como llave y dentro cada valor dentro de otro diccionario con el nombre del archivo para utilizar luego y el minuto más bajo encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

La solución de Marcelo es sin duda la indicada, está que te doy es simplemente para mostrar como se hacían estas cosas en las épocas de las cavernas, dónde solo se contaba con un lista secuencial ordenada y no teníamos estructuras tipo diccionarios en memoria. A esto lo llamábamos "corte de control":

```
def get_primeros_x_hora(files, fechaSelect):

  files_del_dia = sorted([(file[-8:-6],file[-6:-4],file) for file in files if file[12:20] == fechaSelect])

  h_ant = ""
  new_list = []
  for h, m, file in files_del_dia:
    if h_ant != h:
      new_list.append(file)
      h_ant = h

  return(new_list)
```

La lógica es sencilla:

- En primer lugar: `files_del_dia = sorted([(file[-8:-6],file[-6:-4],file) for file in files if file[12:20] == fechaSelect])` con una "comprensión de lista", seleccionamos solo los archivos del día y ordenamos la lista por hora y minuto. `files_del_dia` es una lista de tuplas en la forma `(hora, minuto, file)`
- Luego recorremos secuencialmente la lista y con cada cambio de hora (`if h_ant != h`) nos quedamos con el primer registro, al estar ordenada sabemos que ese primer registro es el del primer minuto de cada hora.